# Issue in Understanding implementation of Common Client Interface

Tags: java, xml, adapter, jdeveloper, saxparser

I am very new to XML, but I have been asked to replace the DOMParser implementation to SAXParser. I referred few tutorials on XML parsers, In spite of this I am unable to understand what is being implemented here.

```
    import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
    import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

    import oracle.xml.parser.v2.DOMParser;
    import oracle.xml.parser.v2.SAXParser;
    import oracle.tip.adapter.api.record.XMLRecordFactory;
    import oracle.tip.adapter.fw.record.XMLRecordFactoryImpl;
    import oracle.tip.adapter.api.record.XMLRecord;
    import oracle.tip.adapter.api.record.RecordElement;
```

---

```
    DOMSource payloadData = getAsDOMSource(xmlPayload);     

    XMLRecordFactory xmlRecordFactory = new XMLRecordFactoryImpl();
    XMLRecord result = xmlRecordFactory.createXMLRecord();

    RecordElement headersRecordElement = xmlRecordFactory.createHeaderRecordElement();
    RecordElement payloadRecordElement = xmlRecordFactory.createPayloadRecordElement();

    payloadRecordElement.setData(payloadData);
    result.setHeaderRecordElement(headersRecordElement);
    result.setPayloadRecordElement(payloadRecordElement);
```

Please help in resolving, an overview will be enough, I shall try the rest.

Comment: This has very little to do with DOM, and everything to do with the so-called Common Client Interface. If you want to reach readers who understand that technology, you will need to use some different tags on your question.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I have updated the tags, please feel free to add others, If I am missing any.